# SharePoint 2010 list - export to Excel 2016 no longer working

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel, export

Export to Excel from a SharePoint 2010 list was previously working fine, but since October/November last year this has stopped working, with the error message 'An unexpected error has occurred. Changes to your data cannot be saved."

If anyone has any ideas to get this working again I'd appreciate it. It may be an office update that has caused this, but I haven't been able to find out which file as yet.

Comment: Is the site listed in your Trusted Sites zone in IE? Not having it always seems to break this functionality for us.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the first things I checked. That and Compatibility View. I was wondering if this was as a result of a KB update because it was working before the year end.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer to this. You need to change the default install of MS Office from 32-bit to 64-bit. Once 32-bit has been removed, reboot, then install 64-bit version it should work.